# I see we're getting trolled about economists being "always wrong"

Tags: discussion, new-users

Based on [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/33052/6210) I have the  impression this is the same "fascism" troll that occasionally posts antisemitic remarks as well.

I dubbed them the "fascism" troll because one of their recurring themes was to ask on politics SE if fascism will succeed "in the end"... and many variations on that.

Economists being "always wrong" seems to be a new theme of them...

On Politics SE a measure [was taken](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/should-we-start-requiring-users-to-register-before-they-can-post-questions) to prohibit unregistered users from posting. This ups the bar somewhat, but not a whole lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the user's account has been destroyed as after reviewing the account i felt that most of the content contributed by the user was not positive or beneficial for the site. Additionally, though its not an explicit rule on the site (Though its probably a mandate by stackexchange in general) any sort of racial remarks or hate speech will not be tolerated.

I would like to have such a policy in place as i think it would improve the quality of content received on the site.

Comment: It's in the [Code of Conduct](https://economics.stackexchange.com/conduct) under Unacceptable Behaviour.